# how to indent multiple lines proportionately in visual code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ascii, indentation

I created a class in python that stores a database of ASCII art strings. I can do this reliably thanks to the triple quotation marks which allows me to use multiple lines. However, the problem with this is that when I attempt to paste the art into their designated variable name within the class, the art is left-aligned with the screen, and doesn't follow the same tab indention like everything else in the class (like I want it to, in other words). If I press Tab or Ctrl + ], it messes up the art by making sure that each line has has exactly 4 spaces, no less.. no more.. I want there to be at least 4 spaces, and if there is already a space between the first character and left side of the text editor window, to add the 4 spaces to it. I can do this manually, but it is quite the drag... any thoughts how to do this in Visual Code?

```
# how it is when pasting
mouseTalking = ("""    
  _   _
 (q\_/p)
  /. .\\
 =\_V_/=   __
  /   \   (
 ((   ))   )
 /\) (/\  /
 \  Y  /-'
 `""^""`       """)

# how I want it to be when pasted (indented)
mouseTalking = ("""    
      _   _
     (q\_/p)
      /. .\\
     =\_V_/=   __
      /   \   (
     ((   ))   )
     /\) (/\  /
     \  Y  /-'
     `""^""`       """)
# what occurs when I indent it using Tab or Ctrl + ]
    mouseTalking = ("""    
    _   _
    (q\_/p)
    /. .\\
    =\_V_/=   __
    /   \   (
    ((   ))   )
    /\) (/\  /
    \  Y  /-'
    `""^""`       """)
```

Comment: don't select the variable name when indenting using tab

Comment: @Zarif doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Move your cursor just before the character (e.g. / \  ( ) ) and then press `tab`.

Also, you can put multiple cursors by pressing `Alt` and clicking the start of every lines' character and then press `tab` to indent then altogether.